# Button pressed in Table View Cell with reusable cells

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I'm struggling with the following problem.

I've got a table view of options for a boat. Each option (cell) has a name, a price and a button that indicates whether the option has been selected or not (see attached screenshot)-

[image]

The problem is that when I tap on a couple of options from Section 1, I get the button_pressed state also for cells in the last section. Probably this happens because cells are reused ?

This is the function that gets called when the cell is tapped, to add the option.

```
- (IBAction)cellButtonSelection:(id)sender {

float prezzoParziale;

UIButton * button = sender;
//NSLog(@"%@",button.superview.superview);
if ([button.superview.superview isKindOfClass:[CellOptions class]] ) {

    CellOptions * cellOpt =(CellOptions *)button.superview.superview;

    //BOOL selectionState = NO;
    cellOpt.selected =! cellOpt.selected;

    if(cellOpt.selected){
        //UIButton *button = cellOpt.button1;
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        prezzoParziale = [cellOpt.label2.text floatValue];
        [accessoriSelezionati addObject:cellOpt.label1.text];
        [accessoriSelezionatiPrezzi addObject: cellOpt.label2.text];

        NSLog(@"stampa: %@", accessoriSelezionati);


    }else{
        //UIButton *button = cellOpt.button1;
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        prezzoParziale = [cellOpt.label2.text floatValue] * -1;
        [accessoriSelezionati removeObject:cellOpt.label1.text];
        [accessoriSelezionatiPrezzi removeObject: cellOpt.label2.text];

    }


 [self updateTotal:prezzoParziale]; }
```

And.....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

        CellOptions * cellOpt;
     cellOpt = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellOption forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cellOpt.label1.text = [[[accessoriXtipologia objectForKey:tipologia] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"nome"];
    cellOpt.label2.text = [[[[accessoriXtipologia objectForKey:tipologia] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"prezzo"] stringValue];

    return cellOpt;

    }
```

EDIT: Now it's working

Added in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cellOpt.selected = [accessoriSelezionati containsObject:cellOpt.label1.text];



            if (cellOpt.selected) {

                [cellOpt.button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }

            else {



            [cellOpt.button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }

            return cellOpt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is due to cell reuse. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, in addition to setting the labels, you've got to set the selected state by doing something like this:

```
cellOpt.selected = [accessoriSelezionati containsObject:cellOpt.label1.text];
```

Comment: I tried to add that line but didn't work. I tried also cellOpt.selected = [accessoriSelezionati containsObject:cellOpt.button1];

Comment: Label1 = name of the option, Label2 = price of the option, Button1 = The button that changes state

Comment: This should work. Did you put my line after the line that sets `cellOpt.label1.text`? If so, please put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and step through to determine exactly what happens. You can use the debugger to inspect the contents of `accessoriSelezionati` and the value of `cellOpt.label1.text` and the resulting value of `cellOpt.selected`. There should be a clue in all of that.

Comment: I added your line plus a couple lines to set the image button, and it seems to work. Thank you.